# How to fetch nested json array in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

I need Fetch this Json But I cant...
please helpe me!!

> Json

```
   [
   "got_new_event",
   {
      "type": "exchange",
      "data": [
         {
            "m": 0.1556,
            "c": "USGLDKG",
            "l": 39264,
            "a": 39264,
            "t": "085542",
            "b": 39257
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

> ReactNative

console.log(event.data) // event.data => json on below

I need get c in data.

Comment: i need get c from data ?????!!!!

Comment: `console.log(res[1].data[0].c)`.....

Comment: tnx, but not working...


Cannot read property '0' of undefined
Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: Upadte my question

Comment: Where are you trying to fetch it from? Can you write up a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Try res[1].data[0].c instead. The main res and data is an array (or JSON array), so you have to access it using the index instead

```js
res = [
   "got_new_event",
   {
      "type": "exchange",
      "data": [
         {
            "m": 0.1556,
            "c": "USGLDKG",
            "l": 39264,
            "a": 39264,
            "t": "085542",
            "b": 39257
         }
      ]
   }
]

console.log(res[1].data[0].c)
```

Try `res[1].data[0].c` instead. The main `res` and `data` is an array (or JSON array), so you have to access it using the index instead

Comment: tnx, but not working...


Cannot read property '0' of undefined
Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: Updated my answer. You can try running it directly there. If it still doesn't work, that means you are posting the wrong json